# Elliptical orbits: Where have I made a mistake?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

Sorry for not using latex, I am new.
Assuming conservation of angular momentum and mechanical energy in an elliptical orbit, the sum of velocities at any two arbitrary points in orbit is constant?  I know this is not true so what is the mistake?

[image: Something is wrong because I know the result is not true.]

Comment: Where is the origin of your coordinate system? What exactly do $r_1$ and $r_2$ represent? I'm guessing that the system is a satellite orbiting a star, in which case shouldn't $|r_1|=|r_2|$? Also, in Equation 2), why is the mass the same in the kinetic energy part on both sides of the equation?

Comment: OP is talking about 1 particle's orbit at some arbitrary times $t_1$ and $t_2$. For that 1 particle, at any two arbitrary times, the angular momentum and mechanical energy will remain constant. That's why OP used the same mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in (i). Angular momentum equation for a point mass would be $\vec{L} = m\vec{r}\times\vec{v}$. The magnitude is therefore $L = mrv\sin\theta$. Since you're in an elliptical orbit (and $\theta\neq 90^\circ$ thus $\sin\theta\neq 1$), the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ will keep changing.

Therefore, your equations for angular momentum magnitude should be
$$L = mr_1v_1\sin\theta_1 \quad {\rm and} \quad L = mr_2v_2\sin\theta_2.$$

Since $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$, you will see that the velocity sum is not constant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! :)